# Sending a string to a Bluetooth serial port using android

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, android-networking

I need to send a string to a Bluetooth serial port of a desktop application.
The android device should be connected to the PC all the time and whenever the mobile gets a call the phone number should be sent to the PC using Bluetooth.
How can i get this done using android?

Comment: There is a readymade code in your Android-SDK folder, App Name : Bluetooth Chat, it provides all the details you want regarding bluetooth communication